# How do i print out a full pyramid with numbers

Tags: c++, nested-loops

so i've been trying to construct a full pyramid that looks like ( https://snag.gy/4yW5hr.jpg )but i've only be able to get the print out for the right side of the pyramid correctly, how do i get the program to display the full pyramid as shown in the screenshot above? Thanks for the assist.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int r,n,s;
cout<<"Enter the desired number of rows:";
cin>>n;

//1st triangle

 for(s=1; s<=n; s++)
 {
    for(r=1; r<=s; r++)
    {
        cout<< r <<"   ";
    }

    cout<< endl;
   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Google search: C++ pyramid. Many examples.

Answer (score 0):

[Example 7](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/pyramid-pattern) is related to your question. You can set the `width` of `std::cout` and `fill` with enough spaces if you want.

A code example, not necessarily the most efficient, is below:

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream &print(std::ostream &output, const int N, bool reverse) {
  if (reverse)
    for (int n = N; n > 1; n--)
      output << n << (n > 9 ? " " : "  ");
  else
    for (int n = 2; n <= N; n++)
      output << (n > 9 ? " " : "  ") << n;
  return output;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int nrows;
  std::cout << "Enter number of rows (1-15): ";
  std::cin >> nrows;
  if (nrows < 1 || nrows > 15) {
    std::cerr << "Number of rows is not in [1,15].\n";
    return 1;
  }

  for (int row = 1; row <= nrows; row++) {
    std::cout.width((nrows - row + 1) * 3);
    std::cout.fill(' ');
    print(std::cout, row, true) << 1;
    print(std::cout, row, false) << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

which gives something like:

```sh
 ~/Desktop  ./a.out
Enter number of rows (1-15): 4
           1
        2  1  2
     3  2  1  2  3
  4  3  2  1  2  3  4
```